# Table Conversions Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've received table 1 which lists a single carton per row and the number of units per column in the carton. I'd like to transform this into table 2 where each carton item has its own row followed by its quantity.

Does anyone have a suggestion?
I'm thinking there is a solution using Match + Index, but perhaps not or else there might be something better. I have dozens of tables to convert and they are much larger than the small excerpt here

Example Table Resolved and Unresolved:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W-mfidCJro73oyPQ0uNy2wwPjxpAlFNn-zM08CAL0u8/edit?usp=sharing

[Table of Cartons and Carton Contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fOm0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a sheet ("Erik Help") with the following formula in A1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Carton","Size/Color","Quantity";QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER(Unresolved!A2:A,Unresolved!A2:A<>"")&"|"&Unresolved!B1:1&"|"&FILTER(INDIRECT("Unresolved!B2:"&ROWS(Unresolved!A:A)),Unresolved!A2:A<>"")),"|",1,0),"Select * Where Col3 Is Not Null")})`

This one formula produces all headers and results.

I applied a custom CF rule to all rows from Row 2 downward to accomplish the shading on alternating rows. This could have been done with **Format > Alternating colors**, but I chose to do it with the custom CF formula for more flexibility.

In short, the formula first creates the three headers. Then it creates a grid that concatenates every non-blank entry in A2:A with every header in B1:1 with every possible intersecting cell value of those two. Each element is concatenated with a pipe symbol between (e.g., 7000|BB09|8, etc.). This grid of all results is then `FLATTEN`ed into one column and `SPLIT` at the pipe symbol into three columns. Finally, `QUERY` weeds out any rows that didn't have a third element (i.e., those which had no value in the grid running down and right from B2).

Comment: This works great Erik Tyler thank you! The formula scales to hundreds of columns and thousands of row nicely. I'm impressed how elegant this answer is too

Comment: Glad it translated easily.